# How to prove this fractional limit is $0$?

Tags: limits, normed-spaces

I guess that
$$\frac{\lambda^2-||y||_\infty^2}{||y||_\infty||x||_1-\langle y, x\rangle}
\xrightarrow{ x\longrightarrow x^*} 0
$$
under the assumptions:

- $f: x\in \mathbb R^n \longmapsto  y\in \mathbb R^n$ is continuous, $x\longrightarrow x^*\neq 0$,
- $||y||_\infty \xrightarrow{  x\longrightarrow x^*} \lambda$ and $||y||_\infty\leq \lambda$, i.e. the nominator is always non-negative and converges to zero.
- $||y||_\infty||x||_1-\langle y, x\rangle \xrightarrow{  x\longrightarrow x^*} 0$, i.e. the denominator is always positive and converges to zero.

I have the intuition that the limit holds true but I have no clues. Could anyone give me some hints how to prove or disprove it?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a counter example as follows:

- Choose $y=f(x)=x$
- Choose $x_k \rightarrow \lambda_{\mathbb R^n}$ such that $x_{k,1}= \lambda-1/k$ and $x_{k,i}=\lambda-1/k-1/2^k$ for $i=2,\ldots, n$.

Then the limit tends to $\infty$ not $0$.